# Japanese Character in Image Path

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I am rendering an Image on browser, but then problem is that the image path contains japanese characters, when it is getting rendered on browser it is by default getting converted into utf-8, example:- 
My image path is something like this - C:\率登録率登録率登録\率登録率登録\率登録\1.jpg, but when I am rendering it on browser it becomes - C:\%E7%8E%87%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E7%8…%BB%E9%8C%B2%E7%8E%87%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2/%E7%8E%87%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2/01.jpg, that browser does't understand and gives error "Failed to load resource"

Answer (score -2):

Be sure to add the charset in the head at the beginning of your page :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

And save your file as UTF8 without BOM file (use notepad++ for that).

Comment: Ideally it's 01.jpg. but i have checked it with 1.jpg as well